# EF Core groupBy no SQL translation for null-coalescing operator (??). ISNULL is not being used to translate when doing ??0m

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

Using EF Core 2.2 with

```
optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
```

A working groupBy linq query to sql server database is failing to evaluate on server side by changing the `Select(t=>t.Value)` to `Select(t=>t.Value??0m)`.

Why is it not being translated to SQL as it could become SUM(ISNULL(Value,0)) ?

I know it's not necessary but I would like to understand how it's working under the hood as I feel I am missing something.

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned any compile time errors, its safe to assume `Value` is nullable. That being said, can you please provide more info, what exception is thrown? Or maybe show the sql prepared by the `IQueryable` interface. I haven't seen entity framework choke on such a simple `.Select`

Comment: yes it's nullable and exception is triggered by QueryClientEvaluationWarning. it's due to the fact that without ??0m it's translated to SQL and evaluated correctly on server side but with ??0m it's not translated and then evaluated on the client side which in my case is triggering an exception because of the warning enablement. There are plenty of discussion on this topic because client side evaluation was default behaviour on ef core 2.2 and has been removed on ef core 3.x

Comment: Can you show atleast part of the table schema, your class model for `t` in this context and the rest of your linq statement?

Comment: table schema can be id, value. (int, int). and the query db.MyTable.GroupBy(t => t.id).Select(g=> new { Id = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(t=>t.Value??0m)}).ToArray();

Comment: Well 0m is basically you saying `(decimal)0`. If `Value` is `typeOf(int)`, should your `.Select` not instead be `.Select(t => t.Value ?? 0)`

Comment: Only reason I am not giving an actual answer is because you haven't provided the property types for your problem in the question. Right now we kind of having a discussion :)

Comment: sorry value is obviously decimal type. Thank you but I don't think all this discussion is relevant to the actual question above unless you want an example to reproduce the issue. And I think I would have the same issue with int? as with decimal? for the value

Comment: Yes please provide sample code that I can use to reproduce the issue without leaving much to my imagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is EF Core 2.2 `GroupBy` query translator defect/limitation (already fixed in EF Core 3.x) which does not support aggregate methods expressions other that simple "property" access.

The workaround is to use intermediate (anonymous type) projection containing all the required expressions (so they become "properties") using the `GroupBy` overload with element selector.

For instance, given entity like this:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SomeKey { get; set; }
    public decimal? SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

and desired, but failing EFC2.2 query like this:

```
var query = db.Set<SomeEntity>()
    .GroupBy(e => e.SomeKey)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        Value = g.Sum(e => e.SomeValue ?? 0m) // <--
    });
```

the modified working EFC2.2 solution could be like this:

```
var query = db.Set<SomeEntity>()
    .GroupBy(e => e.SomeKey, e => new { SomeValue = e.SomeValue ?? 0m }) // <--
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        Value = g.Sum(e => e.SomeValue) // <--
    });
```

More general solution though is to just move the null coalescing operator out of aggregate function:

```
var query = db.Set<SomeEntity>()
    .GroupBy(e => e.SomeKey)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        Value = g.Sum(e => e.SomeValue) ?? 0m // <--
    });
```

Comment: ok thank you but what's happening on the sql translation side? why is  g.Sum(e => e.SomeValue) ?? 0m  working and not  g.Sum(e => e.SomeValue ?? 0m) ? Are you saying that once upgrading to ef core 3 this issue would disappear ?

Comment: Yes, it disappears. As I said at the beginning, this is 2.x defect, which can be fixed with  the temporary projection trick shown in the second variant of the query. Third variant works because `??` is not inside `Sum` method (which is the aforementioned 2.2 limitation/defect).